# Erro: em ng-options [orderBy:notarray]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Está dando um erro no console que não consigo descobrir

> Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received

A lista está vindo correta no combobox, mas da o erro que mencionei.

Segue o HTML e o Angular como estou fazendo:

```
function carregaCadastro() {    
    var cad = gatewayClient.delivery('cadastro').request('lista');
    requestMonitor.add('formCadstro', cad);
    gatewayClient.execute(cad).then(function(result) {
        $scope.cadastro = result.data.value;
    })
}
```

```
<div class="col">
  <select class="form-control"  name="cadastro " ng-options="cadastro.nome for cadastro  in (cadastro  | orderBy:'noem') track by cadastro.id" ng-model="cadastro"  id="cadastro">
    <option value="" disabled selected> -- Selecione -- </option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Tem como dar um console.log em `cadastro` e mostrar a saída na pergunta?

Comment: é só um erro de digitação em `orderBy:'noem'` ou o correto seria `orderBy:'nome'`?

Comment: o correto é nome mesmo foi erro de digitação